# Are visible type applications a safe alternative to `Proxy` arguments?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given that with visible type application one can now populate ambiguous types for a value or function, can this now substitute the use of Proxy entirely?

A downside I see is that one may have to enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, but as not allowing ambiguous type used to catch type signatures that were left ambiguous by mistake then this safety net won't be there anymore. Are there any other issues one should think about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern code, I try to avoid `Proxy` as much as I can, preferring ambiguous types and type applications. I can't see any downside to doing that.

Still, if I recall correctly, there are some corner cases where we still need something like `Proxy`. For instance:

```
class    C a    where name :: String
instance C Int  where name = "Int"
instance C Bool where name = "Bool"

data T where
   T :: forall a . C a => !(Proxy a) -> T

t1 :: T
t1 = T @Int Proxy

t2 :: T
t2 = T @Bool Proxy

nameFromT :: T -> String
nameFromT (T (Proxy :: Proxy a)) = name @a
```

Without `Proxy`, I don't know how to bind the type to `a` in the last line:

```
data T where
   T :: forall a . C a => T

t1 :: T
t1 = T @Int

t2 :: T
t2 = T @Bool

nameFromT :: T -> String
nameFromT (T @a) = name @a
--  Error:
--    Type applications in patterns are not yet supported
```

In this specific case the best I can do is to resort to `Dict`.

```
data T where
   T :: forall a . Dict (C a) -> T
```

Still, it is still `Proxy`-like in that `T` now has a visible (non-type-level) argument that should not be there.

Comment: A downside of ambiguous types is that it can cause unpleasant error messages (ambiguous types are usually bugs, but now these bugs are not caught as soon as possible). I'll stick with proxies until [visible forall](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0281-visible-forall.rst) is implemented.

Comment: @Noughtmare I say the same in the second paragraph of the question. :)

But thanks for the link to visible forall!

Comment: See also [Allow visible type application in patterns](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/11350). It's closed, so maybe a new enough GHC allows this.

Comment: @DanielWagner it links to a [merged merge request !2464](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/2464) where milestone is 9.2.1, so probably that version of GHC.

Comment: An alternative to an extra argument is `Tagged`. It's not very pleasant, but it works.

Comment: @DanielWagner see [this comment and the one below it in that thread](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/11350#note_318629), that issue is only about visible type applications **on constructors** in patterns. General visible type applications in patterns are suggested in [this GHC proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/238).

Comment: @Noughtmare ...isn't the type application pattern in this answer on a constructor?

Comment: @dfeuer Can `Tagged` be used in the example above `data T where T :: forall a . C a => T` ? I tried to use it, but with no other arguments in the constructor I can't see where to add the tag.

Comment: (@dfeuer has perhaps something to add to this, but) @chi given a case where no value is required (as in the `T` you mention) then no, `Tagged` can't be used.

`Tagged a b` is just a newtype with two type parameters, one phantom (`a`) and one that says what type of value it has inside (`b`), and as it's a newtype it has the runtime performance of simply having a straight `b`, which I presume is better than having a `Proxy` as that has a runtime value for itself too (for the `Proxy` that actually carries only the type).

Comment: I tried it. GHC 9.2 does indeed make this possible without proxies; it is `nameFromT (T @_ @a) = name @a`. The first `@_` binds a kind, because `C` is poly-kinded.

Comment: @chi, oh, I missed that. It might not work there. Fortunately, making that proxy strict unpacks it to nothing.

Comment: @DanielWagner Excellent news. With that and visible foralls I guess in the future we can retire all the uses of `Proxy`, I think.